# RETURN PREVIOUS CONTROLLER UIbutton action

Tags: swift, controller, uibutton, action, root

I want the method to implement in UIbutton action to return to a previous controller, when button is tapped.
Regards
Very grateful for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 Xcode 8**

```
@IBAction func close(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    dismiss(animated: true , completion: nil)
}
```